# Sign in with google is not working in android release version

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using google sign in my app using firebase. Everything works perfectly with debug apk. but after submitting the close testing release the google sign in function is returning error code :10. I Have added the sha-1 key generated using my Keystore and from play store "App sign in". is there any else i should do or check?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add your production keys properly, only your debug keystore.

Comment: i did that too. :(